# TableOne with multiple factors and same levels converts labels in silenced output

Tags: r

I have multiple factors in a dataframe and I want to make a nice table with renamed variables and TableOne. But when I specify to "showAllLevels" then the labels of the variables in the saved output are messed-up (spaces and special chars replaced with dots)

```
library(tableone)
library(labelled)
library(dplyr)

hyp <- c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1)
dia <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0)

hyp <- as.factor(hyp)
dia <- as.factor(dia)

df <- data.frame(hyp, dia)

df <- df %>% 
  rename(`Hypertention (%)` = hyp, `Type II Diabetes (%)` = dia)

tab1 <- CreateTableOne(data = df)

tab1_word <- print(tab1, showAllLevels = T, varLabels = T)
view(tab1_word)
```

And here are the outputs:
Produces a nice output in the console

[image: Produces a nice output in the console]

But the in the saved output, the labels are messed-up

[image: But the in the saved output, the labels are messed-up]

Is there a way to fix this? In the end I have maybe 30 factors with yes/no, 1/0, True/False and would like to export to a word file or .csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has to do with how rownames are treated.
If we use as_tibble() with rownames = "string" it seems to work.

Example code below:

```
library(tableone)
library(labelled) # Not needed?
library(dplyr)
library(tibble) # For as_tibble

hyp <- c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1)
dia <- c(0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0)

hyp <- as.factor(hyp)
dia <- as.factor(dia)

df <- data.frame(hyp, dia)

df <- df %>% 
  rename(`Hypertention (%)` = hyp, `Type II Diabetes (%)` = dia)

tab1 <- CreateTableOne(data = df)

# Use explain = F, otherwise you will have (%) two times
tab1_word <- print(tab1, 
                   quote = F, 
                   noSpaces = T,  
                   test = F, 
                   contDigits = 1, 
                   printToggle = F,
                   dropEqual = T, 
                   explain = F, 
                   showAllLevels = T)

tab1_df <- as_tibble(tab1_word, rownames = "Variable")
View(tab1_df)
```